# Trying to get data from android studio screen

Tags: android, android-edittext

Probably a really stupid question but i can't seem to get the data that someone enters in a textview on the screen to work in my code? Ive currently got this but it doesn't work?

code file:

```
 String text = textlabel.Txt.getText().toString();
```

display view:

```
   <EditText
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/textlabel"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:layout_weight="0.31"
       android:background="#df8a8a"
       android:inputType="text"
       android:editable="true" />
```

Comment: you need declare your **EditText** in java for example:  EditText textlabel;

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this in your activity main:

```
EditText textlabel  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textlabel);
String text = textlabel.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a `EditText` in your class outside the `onCreate()` method like

```
EditText textlabel;
```

Then in `onCreate()` write

```
textlabel  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textlabel);
```

Now from anywhere you can get the text by

```
String entered = textlabel.getText().toString();
```